# Android Locale app - R's full package name

Tags: android, resources

This is the source to Locale section that's in the Settings
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/gingerbread-release/src/com/android/settings/LocalePicker.java

Does anyone know what is the full package name for the `R` class? Oddly enough its not in the import list NOR is it in the **com / android / settings** package.

I want `R.array.special_locale_codes` for my own needs.

Comment: On the same note, what the heck does R even stand for? I think resources, but I could never be sure.

Comment: Yeah, "R" is the shortest identifier (one letter) and it represents access to names in the Resources file hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

Getting `R.array.special_locale_codes` is irrelevant if there isn't any `res/values/nameofxmlcontainingarray.xml`

There `must be xml file` inside `res/values/nameofxmlcontainingarray.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>  
<array name="special_locale_codes">  
<item>first</item>  
<item>second</item>  
<item>third</item>  
<item>fourth</item>  
<item>fifth</item>  
 </array>
</resources>
```

`R.array.special_locale_codes` is generated file at the built time. `Manually editing R.java is totally un-recommended.`

`R.java` contains `resources which are defined inside your project which can be wired up with java code at built time`. Getting `resources from project` can be `done using R.id.componentname`

`FIX` :`If your project do contains proper resources at defined structure then you may give a try to clean your project using rightclick project->clean project`